# Form elements on IPAD not clickable

Tags: html, forms, ipad

I have a form on the IPAD and none of the elements are clickable. Other buttons within the page are clickable. I stripped the page right back to just have the form in there, because I thought maybe something was overlapping it. Works fine on desktop browsers.

Any suggestions?

```
   <form action="#/search" method="GET">
    <label>Show:</label>
    <input type="text" name="query" value=""/>
    <label>Duration:</label>
    <input class="number" type="number" name="cycle" value="10"/>
    <label>Queue:</label>
    <input class="number" type="number" name="queue" value="20"/>
    <label>Event Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="eventname" value="Conference 2013"/>
    <label>Cycle Colour?</label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="true" checked="true"/>
    <label>Zoom?</label>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="zoom" value="true" checked="true"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="go"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: With not clickable you mean that you can't even input text into the textfields?

Comment: Have you tried making it post to a regular action, instead of the `#` url? I'm not able to test anything without an iPad, but that could be an issue maybe...

Comment: Can you add de CSS code? There are some properties aplied to form elements that can be problematic (like "-webkit-user-select").

Comment: OK thanks for you help. It was something i had set on the form element. The z-index was set to something it shouldnt. Shouldnt be setting styles on the form element i guess :S Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and in my case it was a update from iScroll.js to the new Version, after reverting this update it work again.